# Why can R be linked to a shared BLAS later even if it was built with `--with-blas = lblas`?

Tags: r, ubuntu, blas, openblas

The [BLAS section in R installation and administration manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#BLAS) says that when R is built **from source**, with configuration parameter `--without-blas`, it will build Netlib's reference BLAS into a standalone shared library at `R_HOME/lib/libRblas.so`, along side the standard R shared library `R_HOME/lib/libR.so`. This makes it easier for user to switch and benchmark different tuned BLAS in R environment. The guide suggests that researcher might use symbolic link to `libRblas.so` to achieve this, and [this article](http://www.rochester.edu/college/psc/thestarlab/help/moreclus/BLAS.pdf) gives more details on this.

On contrary, when simply installing a pre-compiled binary version of R, either from R CRAN's mirrors or Ubuntu's repository (for linux user like me), **in theory** it should be more difficult to switch between different BLAS without rebuilding R, because a pre-compiled R version is configured with `--with-blas = (some blas library)`. We can easily check this, either by reading configuration file at `R_HOME/etc/Makeconf`, or check the result of `R CMD config BLAS_LIBS`. For example, on my machine it returns `-lblas`, so it is linked to reference BLAS **at build time**. As a result, there is no `R_HOME/lib/libRblas.so`, only `R_HOME/lib/libR.so`.

However, [this R-blog](http://edustatistics.org/nathanvan/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/) says that it is possible to switch between difference BLAS, even if R is not installed from source. The author tried the ATLAS and OpenBLAS from ubuntu's repository, and then use `update-alternatives --config` to work around. It is also possible to configure and install tuned BLAS from source, add them to "alternatives" through `update-alternatives --install`, and later switch between them in the same way. The BLAS library (a symbolic link) in this case will be found at `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`, which is under both ubuntu and R's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I have tested and this does work! **But I am very surprised at how R achieves this.**  As I said, R should have been tied to the BLAS library configured at building time, i.e., I would expect all BLAS routines integrated into `R_HOME/lib/libR.so`. So why is it still possible to change BLAS via `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`?

Thanks if someone can please explain this.

Comment: I once tried to explain all this in [this vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf) to the [gcbd](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/index.html) package.  On Debian and Ubuntu is just works as seen by that package...

Comment: I don't have time to debug your local issue, nor do I have enough information but I would think that something goes wrong with your setup / `configure` options.  Make sure you _also_ request dynamic linking.

Comment: This can be hair-splittingly complicated.  Maybe one easier bet for you would be to replicate something a la gbcd on a Debian/Ubuntu box and then try to insert your locally built R to test the setup.  Good luck!