# R: any faster R function than "tcrossprod" for symmetric dense matrix multiplication?

Tags: r, matrix, hpc

Let

```
x = matrix(rnorm(1000000), nrow = 5000)
```

I would like to compute matrix multiplication with its transpose: `x %*% t(x)`.

After googling I found a possible faster way of doing the above is

```
tcrossprod(x)
```

And time taken is

```
 user  system elapsed 
2.975   0.000   2.960
```

Is there is any other R-function which can do the task faster than the above function?

Comment: Do you have all doubles as in your example? It's rare that I have a matrix this size with no zeroes or integers. The time is drastically increased with the format you are showing.

Comment: @PierreLafortune. The actual matrix I am dealing with is consists of integers and fractions as elements. The output matrix is a covariance matrix.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I want to compute the eigen values and vectors using the r function "eigen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At R level this is already the fastest. But internally it calls level-3 BLAS routine `dsyrk`. So if you can have a high performance BLAS library this will be a lot faster. Try linking [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) to your R.

Linking a BLAS library does not require rebuilding R. You may have a read on my question [linking R to BLAS library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36996079/4891738) for an overview, which contains several links showing you how to set up alias then switch between different BLAS libraries on the machine.

Alternatively, you can read my extremely long question and answer [Without root access, run R with tuned BLAS when it is linked with reference BLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37041819/4891738) which gives various ways to use an external BLAS library even if R is linked to reference BLAS library.

---

As a side note, for a matrix with dimension `m * n`, `dsyrk` has FLOP counts `n * m ^ 2`. *(Note, this is the computational costs for `tcrossprod`. For `crossprod` it is `m * n ^ 2`.)*

You have `m = 5000` and `n = 200`, and computation takes `2.96s`. Thus, computation has speed: `(200 * 5000 ^ 2 / 2.96) * 1e-9 = 1.68 GFLOPs`. Well, this is an ordinary level of performance so at the moment you are definitely using reference BLAS. With `OpenBLAS`, performance can reach `10 GFLOPs` or more, depending on your CPU. Good luck!