# Ridge regression with `glmnet` gives different coefficients than what I compute by "textbook definition"?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, glmnet

I am running Ridge regression with the use of `glmnet` `R` package. I noticed that the coefficients I obtain from `glmnet::glmnet` function are different from those I get by computing coefficients by definition (with the use of the same lambda value). Could somebody explain me why?

Data (both: response `Y` and design matrix `X`) are scaled.

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)

# Data dimensions
p.tmp <- 100
n.tmp <- 100

# Data objects
set.seed(1)
X <- scale(mvrnorm(n.tmp, mu = rep(0, p.tmp), Sigma = diag(p.tmp)))
beta <- rep(0, p.tmp)
beta[sample(1:p.tmp, 10, replace = FALSE)] <- 10
Y.true <- X %*% beta
Y <- scale(Y.true + matrix(rnorm(n.tmp))) # Y.true + Gaussian noise

# Run glmnet 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se

# Extract coefficient values for lambda.1se (without intercept)
ridge.coef <- (coef(ridge.fit.cv, s = ridge.fit.lambda))[2:(p.tmp+1)]

# Get coefficients "by definition"
ridge.coef.DEF <- solve(t(X) %*% X + ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y

# Plot estimates
plot(ridge.coef, type = "l", ylim = range(c(ridge.coef, ridge.coef.DEF)),
     main = "black: Ridge `glmnet`\nred: Ridge by definition")
lines(ridge.coef.DEF, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: This is really a request for statistical tutoring and as such is more appropriate for CrossValidated.com. (I think the answer is that ridge regression is a penalized method, but you would probably get a more authoritative answer from the CV crowd.)

Comment: @42- It seems like this is actually a coding question. If I understand correctly, the OP is asking why the coefficients returned by `glmnet` for a given value of lambda (the penalty term) are not the same as the coefficients he gets by solving for the regression coefficients directly using the same value of lambda as `glmnet`.

Comment: Interestingly, the OP's "by hand" calculation with `100*ridge.fit.lambda` results in (almost) exactly the same coefficients from `solve(t(X) %*% X + 100*ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y` as you get from `glmnet` with `ridge.fit.lambda`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you read `?glmnet`, you will see that the penalized objective function of Gaussian response is:

```
1/2 * RSS / nobs + lambda * penalty
```

In case the ridge penalty `1/2 * ||beta_j||_2^2` is used, we have

```
1/2 * RSS / nobs + 1/2 * lambda * ||beta_j||_2^2
```

which is proportional to

```
RSS + lambda * nobs * ||beta_j||_2^2
```

**This is different to what we usually see in textbook regarding ridge regression:**

```
RSS + lambda * ||beta_j||_2^2
```

The formula you write:

```
##solve(t(X) %*% X + ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
drop(solve(crossprod(X) + diag(ridge.fit.lambda, p.tmp), crossprod(X, Y)))
```

is for the textbook result; for `glmnet` we should expect:

```
##solve(t(X) %*% X + n.tmp * ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
drop(solve(crossprod(X) + diag(n.tmp * ridge.fit.lambda, p.tmp), crossprod(X, Y)))
```

So, the textbook uses **penalized least squares**, but `glmnet` uses **penalized mean squared error**.

Note I did not use your original code with `t()`, `"%*%"` and `solve(A) %*% b`; using `crossprod` and `solve(A, b)` is more efficient! See *Follow-up* section in the end.

---

Now let's make a new comparison:

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)

# Data dimensions
p.tmp <- 100
n.tmp <- 100

# Data objects
set.seed(1)
X <- scale(mvrnorm(n.tmp, mu = rep(0, p.tmp), Sigma = diag(p.tmp)))
beta <- rep(0, p.tmp)
beta[sample(1:p.tmp, 10, replace = FALSE)] <- 10
Y.true <- X %*% beta
Y <- scale(Y.true + matrix(rnorm(n.tmp)))

# Run glmnet 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, intercept = FALSE)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se

# Extract coefficient values for lambda.1se (without intercept)
ridge.coef <- (coef(ridge.fit.cv, s = ridge.fit.lambda))[-1]

# Get coefficients "by definition"
ridge.coef.DEF <- drop(solve(crossprod(X) + diag(n.tmp * ridge.fit.lambda, p.tmp), crossprod(X, Y)))

# Plot estimates
plot(ridge.coef, type = "l", ylim = range(c(ridge.coef, ridge.coef.DEF)),
     main = "black: Ridge `glmnet`\nred: Ridge by definition")
lines(ridge.coef.DEF, col = "red")
```

[image]

Note that I have set `intercept = FALSE` when I call `cv.glmnet` (or `glmnet`). This has more conceptual meaning than what it will affect in practice. Conceptually, our textbook computation has no intercept, so we want to drop intercept when using `glmnet`. But practically, since your `X` and `Y` are standardized, the theoretical estimate of intercept is 0. Even with `intercepte = TRUE` (`glment` default), you can check that the estimate of intercept is `~e-17` (numerically 0), hence estimate of other coefficients is not notably affected. The other answer is just showing this.

---

**Follow-up**

> As for the using `crossprod` and `solve(A, b)` - interesting! Do you by chance have any reference to simulation comparison for that?

`t(X) %*% Y` will first take transpose `X1 <- t(X)`, then do `X1 %*% Y`, while `crossprod(X, Y)` will not do the transpose. `"%*%"` is a wrapper for [`DGEMM`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html#gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1) for case `op(A) = A, op(B) = B`, while `crossprod` is a wrapper for `op(A) = A', op(B) = B`. Similarly `tcrossprod` for `op(A) = A, op(B) = B'`.

A major use of `crossprod(X)` is for `t(X) %*% X`; similarly the `tcrossprod(X)` for `X %*% t(X)`, in which case [`DSYRK`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/d05/dsyrk_8f.html) instead of `DGEMM` is called. You can read **the first section** of [Why the built-in lm function is so slow in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919817/4891738) for reason and a benchmark.

Be aware that if `X` is not a square matrix, `crossprod(X)` and `tcrossprod(X)` are not equally fast as they involve different amount of floating point operations, for which you may read **the side notice** of [Any faster R function than “tcrossprod” for symmetric dense matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532224/4891738)

Regarding `solvel(A, b)` and `solve(A) %*% b`, please read **the first section** of [How to compute diag(X %*% solve(A) %*% t(X)) efficiently without taking matrix inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534036/4891738)

Comment: **Zheyuan Li**, I appreciate your answer greatly! As for the *using `crossprod` and `solve(A, b)`* - interesting! Do you by chance have any reference to simulation comparison for that? It is efficient in a time-computing sense only or yields some better underneath computational solution that result in more precision while computing some "troublesome" matrices (very large or with high amplitude of values)? One drawback I can see is that it makes the code less lucid than chain `%*%` operation.

Comment: **Zheyuan Li**, thanks for following-up! I will definitely check these links over the weekend. Bests!

Answer (score 4):

Adding on top of Zheyuan's interesting post, did some more experiments to see that we can get the same results with intercept as well, as follows:

```
# ridge with intercept glmnet
ridge.fit.cv.int <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, intercept = TRUE, family="gaussian")
ridge.fit.lambda.int <- ridge.fit.cv.int$lambda.1se
ridge.coef.with.int <- as.vector(as.matrix(coef(ridge.fit.cv.int, s = ridge.fit.lambda.int)))

# ridge with intercept definition, use the same lambda obtained with cv from glmnet
X.with.int <- cbind(1, X)
ridge.coef.DEF.with.int <- drop(solve(crossprod(X.with.int) + ridge.fit.lambda.int * diag(n.tmp, p.tmp+1), crossprod(X.with.int, Y)))

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(ridge.coef.with.int, ridge.coef.DEF.with.int))
```

[image]

```
# comupte residuals
RSS.fit.cv.int <- sum((Y.true - predict(ridge.fit.cv.int, newx=X))^2) # predict adds inter
RSS.DEF.int <- sum((Y.true - X.with.int %*% ridge.coef.DEF.with.int)^2)

RSS.fit.cv.int
[1] 110059.9
RSS.DEF.int
[1] 110063.4
```

Comment: Hi **sandipan**, thank you for this post! I am even surprised that the residuals difference is noticeable (not: super-marginal difference of 1e-10 or smaller order). In the case of this post all I actually cared was simplicity in adjusting the two vectors on the same plot (I needed to make them consistent in length).

Comment: @MartaKaras but the difference is quite small if you consider the magnitude of RSS, it's (110063.4-110059.9)/110063.4 = 3.179985e-05.